# Visual Studio IPC API : Accessing and modifying projects from outside

Tags: c++, visual-studio, api, ipc

I'm currently working to extend some of our own tools (external from VS) to support communication with Visual Studio, to generate and add new code files to existing projects, and preferably also ask a visual studio instance for the currently open solution file to find the right process to talk to.

Right now the only way for me to do this is to directly access the project XML file, and add the files on my own, and then tell windows to open my new file, and hope it get opened in the right visual studio instance... and visual studio will most likely ask me if I want to reload the changes in the project file.

This feels like a very brute force and roundabout way to do it, so I suspect there might be some better way, but all my searched have given me no results. It might be because all searches for IPC and Visual Studio just gives me results with others working with IPC related stuff in visual studio, and all I can find about visual studios API is team oriented or for extensions. If anyone could directly me in the right direction to find more info about this, or anything similar, it would be great!

(if easily doable from C++ is a plus, but if I need to wrap a DLL or use other scripts it's okay as well)

Thanks!